Connect ASP .NET Core to Cognito User Pools
I need to develop a system using ASP .NET Core 8.0 with MVC, where I can authenticate users through a login (which I already have) against my Cognito user pool. I've seen some tutorials, but the issue is that they explain how to do it with Cognito's internal login, whereas I need it to work with the custom login design that I'm using. Can someone help me with this? I'm attaching the code for my login and controller.
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 card-left card-left-information">
            <div>
                <h1 class="title-card-left roboto-bold">¡Bienvenido!</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="text-card-left roboto-medium">
                <p>Por favor, introduce tus credenciales<br/> para acceder.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 card-right">
            <div class="text-center mb-5">
                <h3 class="title-medium roboto-regular">Inicio de <br />Sesión</h3>
            </div>
            <form asp-controller="Auth" asp-action="LoginProccess" class="form">
                <div class="form-group mb-4 grupo-formulario">
                    <label class="text-light roboto-light formulario-label">Correo</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control-lg input-form" name="Email"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group mb-5 grupo-formulario ">
                    <label class="text-light formulario-label">Contraseña</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control-lg input-form" name="Password" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Iniciar Sesion" class="btn btn-primary p-3 px-5 " />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img src="/img/Logo-3.webp" id="logos-footer" alt="Alternate Text" />
</div>

and this is my controller
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace IgnaSys.Controllers
{
    public class AuthController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult LoginProccess(IFormCollection formCollection)
        {
            string _correo = formCollection["Email"];
            string _clave = formCollection["Password"];

            if (_correo == "admin")
            {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
              
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Auth");
        }

        public IActionResult Logout()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}


I've been trying to do it following the approach explained in the link, but it hasn't worked for me. In fact, I encounter an error when attempting to implement it.
https://coderjony.com/blogs/authenticating-users-in-aspnet-core-mvc-using-amazon-cognito

What error are you getting?

We have published Authentication flow examples with.NET for Amazon Cognito code samples on GitHub, which shows how to use Cognito authentication flows with .NET. You can use the ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH auth flow for your custom requirement.
